# Why is my interaction observer not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, intersection-observer

I am very confused with my interaction observer, I've tried `threshold: 1`, `if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.99)`, `if (entry.intersectionRatio === 1)`, and `if (entry.isIntersecting)` but nothing's working, the only time my animations 'kinda work' is when I did `threshold: [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1],` and `if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.25)`, however, I want my images to animate on scroll, when they're fully scrolled to view, not when they're 25% scrolled to view, am I misunderstanding something?

I'm using Nuxt.js + tailwindcss

**Problem Code:**

```
<div
      class="container flex flex-col items-center gap-4 px-4 pt-4 mx-auto mt-4 md:grid md:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-12 md:px-8"
    >
      <div class="start-at-left col-span-full md:col-span-6 lg:col-span-8">
        <BannerComponent
          :mobile-image="banners[0].mobileImage"
          :tablet-image="banners[0].tabletImage"
          :laptop-image="banners[0].laptopImage"
          :desktop-image="banners[0].desktopImage"
          :default-image="banners[0].defaultImage"
          :banners-link="banners[0].link"
        />
      </div>
      
    </div>

    <section class="my-12">
      <div
        class="container flex flex-col items-center gap-4 px-4 pt-4 mx-auto mt-4 md:flex-row md:grid md:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-12 md:px-8"
      >
        
        <!-- Here, you should use the first banner from the banners array or define another data property for this banner -->
        <div class="start-at-right md:col-span-3 lg:col-span-8">
          <BannerComponent
            :mobile-image="banners[1].mobileImage"
            :tablet-image="banners[1].tabletImage"
            :laptop-image="banners[1].laptopImage"
            :desktop-image="banners[1].desktopImage"
            :default-image="banners[1].defaultImage"
            :banner-link="banners[1].link"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

```
mounted() {
    this.setupObserver();
  },

 methods: {

    setupObserver() {
      const options = {
        root: null,
        threshold: [1],
      };

      const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        console.log('Callback executed!'); // <-- Add this line
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          console.log(
            `Element: ${entry.target.className}, Intersection Ratio: ${entry.intersectionRatio}`,
          );

          if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.99) {
            // Adjust this value as needed
            if (entry.target.classList.contains('start-at-left')) {
              entry.target.classList.add('slide-to-right');
            } else if (entry.target.classList.contains('start-at-right')) {
              entry.target.classList.add('slide-to-left');
            }
          }
        });
      }, options);

      document
        .querySelectorAll('.start-at-left, .start-at-right, .ease-up')
        .forEach((el) => {
          observer.observe(el);
        });
    },
  },
```

**tailwind.css:**

```
/* Initial states */
.start-at-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s; /* Adjust duration as needed */
}

.start-at-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s; /* Adjust duration as needed */
}

/* Animated states */
.slide-to-right {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 30;
}

.slide-to-left {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 30;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that at the start of your animation your element is not in view - because it will be animated into it? Or when you animation starts it gets moved out of view again?

Comment: Is that how interaction observer works? The images do have an initial position that is off screen so they can't be seen until 'scrolled' to, I was assuming interaction observer would take into account their final position as the 'viewable' or 'intersecting' area. However, if it does work this way, why did ``threshold: [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]``, and ``if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.25)`` work? I'm still confused.

Comment: Nono, intersection observer does not make assumptions about your objects. It can't know what the 'final' destination of your objects are gonna be. You would need some sort of marker that _can_ scroll into view. (I mean what if you animate something to go off screen? Should it still be marked as intersecting if its default position does but its current animation with animation-fill-mode doesnt?) The reason those worked is probably because as soon as your element was intersecting, you moved it off screen un-intersecting it with the animation.

Comment: I will try update their initial positions then and see how it goes. Thanks for the help I did not know that!

Comment: Good luck! Let me know if it worked, because if it didn't I'll gladly remove my comments to give this question another try. Although when that happens, you should try to get this into a snippet we can run here, so no compilers, react etc... Just the base code outputted by those.